# Elm unit testing and Code Coverage

Tags: elm

Is there a way to calculate code coverage for unit tests for Elm language?

I understand that Elm is compiled into JavaScript and I do can read it for "hello world" type of examples, but code coverage measured for generated JS code is not what I want to see - I want to see code coverage for the original source code lines.

Answer (score 2):

Currently code coverage of Elm source code is not supported. I'm pretty sure that code coverage is one of those non-trivial things that you can't just hack in there quickly.

So I think the best course of action is starting a discussion on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/elm-discuss). The idea will get more attention there, and perhaps someone will be interested in taking it up as a project.

Comment: Thank you! Started. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elm-discuss/t3ENhYAFx2U

Comment: Has there been any _progress_ on this in the last 2 years...?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool that does code coverage for Elm code.  It's at https://github.com/zwilias/elm-coverage.